# sklearn linear regression for 2D array

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray

I have a Numpy 2D array in which the rows are individual time series and the columns correspond to the time points.  I would like to fit a regression line to each of the rows to measure the trends of each time series, which I guess I could do (inefficiently) with a loop like:

```
array2D = ...
for row in array2D:
    coeffs = sklearn.metrics.LinearRegression().fit( row, range( len( row ) ).coef_
    ...
```

Is there a way to do this without a loop?  What is the resulting shape of `coeffs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coefficients that minimize the linear regression error are

[image]

You can solve for all rows in one go using numpy.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def solve(timeseries):

    n_samples = timeseries.shape[1]
    # slope and offset/bias
    n_features = 2
    n_series = timeseries.shape[0]

    # For a single time series, X would be of shape
    # (n_samples, n_features) however in this case
    # it will be (n_samples. n_features, n_series)
    # The bias is added by having features being all 1's
    X = np.ones((n_samples, n_features, n_series))
    X[:, 1, :] = timeseries.T

    y = np.arange(n_samples)

    # A is the matrix to be inverted and will
    # be of shape (n_series, n_features, n_features)
    A = X.T @ X.transpose(2, 0, 1)
    A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A) 

    # Do the other multiplications step by step
    B = A_inv @ X.T
    C = B @ y 

    # Return only the slopes (which is what .coef_ does in sklearn)
    return C[:,1]

array2D = np.random.random((3,10))
coeffs_loop = np.empty(array2D.shape[0])
for i, row in enumerate(array2D):
    coeffs = LinearRegression().fit( row[:,None], range( len( row ) )).coef_
    coeffs_loop[i] = coeffs

coeffs_vectorized = solve(array2D)

print(np.allclose(coeffs_loop, coeffs_vectorized))
```

Comment: Hmmm...   two further questions:
1.   Why not use sklearn.metrics.LinearRegression instead of rolling your own?
2.   Can we eliminate the "for" loop somehow?  My array2D has >200k rows.

Comment: 1) Because `sklearn` doesn't do what you need it to do. The `LinearRegression` method assumes that you pass it an array of shape `(n_samples, n_features)`. 2) The only for-loop in the above code is to validate that the `solve` function gets the correct answer.

Comment: @MarkLavin Alternatively `LinearRegression().fit(array2D.T, np.arange(array2D.shape[1])).coef_)` will approximately give you the same answer if you have many more samples than time series, but that doesn't sound like it's the case.

Comment: Can you explain why you prefer, for time serie, the format
`LinearRegression().fit(THE_TIMESERIE, THE_RANGE)`

instead of

`LinearRegression().fit(THE_RANGE, THE_TIMESERIE)`
?

I keep thinking about it and I still don't understand why to use the first version.

Comment: @BernardoResolve because that is what the OP used, and swapping them would solve the inverse regression problem.

Answer (score 2):

For those like me who prefer the range as X and the timeserie data as y.

[image]

```
def linear_fit(periods, timeseries):
    # just format and add one column initialized at 1
    X_mat=np.vstack((np.ones(len(periods)), periods)).T
    
    # cf formula : linear-regression-using-matrix-multiplication
    tmp = np.linalg.inv(X_mat.T.dot(X_mat)).dot(X_mat.T)
    return tmp.dot(timeseries.T)[1] # 1 => coef_, 0 => intercept_

X = np.arange(8) # the periods, or the common range for all time series

y = np.array([ # time series
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 73.92, 0., 114.32],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 73.92, 0., 114.32],
    [0., 10., 20., 30., 40., 50., 60., 70.]
])

linear_fit(X, y)
[1]: array([12.16666667, 12.16666667, 10.        ])
```

PS:This approach (linear regression with matrix multiplication) is a gold mine for large dataset